# sudo add-apt-repository - command not found (GParted Live CD)

Tags: debian, gparted

I am [trying to burn a DVD using GParted](https://superuser.com/questions/454938/how-to-burn-a-dvd-from-within-gparted-live-cd) (not a DVD *of GParted*).

I see that GParted uses a Debian distro (Wheezy). I am trying to install dvd+rw-tools:

```
sudo apt-get install dvd+rw-tools
```

> Package dvd+rw-tools is not availble, but is referred to by another
>   package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or  is only availble from another source

Fine. Then I try to add another repository:

```
sudo apt-add repository ppa:ferramroberto/extra
```

> sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found

Then, I try to install `python-software-properties`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

And get

> Unable to locate package python-software-properties

How can I make this work?

Comment: have you performed an apt-get upadte after adding the repository?

Comment: @Momo - I don't remember anymore. I eventually found the OS disk, so I didn't need to solve this problem. For those who need it, this might help: http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?pid=29773#p29773

Comment: A bit similar to http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?id=16600

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't use ppa repos for this. The `dvd+rw-tools` package is available in the main debian repositories. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add this line:

```
deb ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

The update the list of available packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Now you should be able to install `dvd+rw-tools`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dvd+rw-tools
```

You probably don't even need to do that. If you follow the instructions given in the link you provide in your question and try to install `wodim`, it should also install all its dependencies. If the correct repository is present everything should work.

Comment: You need an apt-get update in there. I'm going to go ahead and edit it in for you, feel free to revert if you disagree.

Comment: I think you need to refer to the wheezy repo (see the OP)

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

`apt-get install software-properties-common`

Comment: Welcome here. Note, magician answers like *"just run &$§%"§$% and it will work"* don't look very well. Explain the background to the OP.

Comment: They also tend to age *spectacularly poorly*.